# Determine the process pid  listening on a certain port

Tags: unix, port, freebsd, pid

As the title says, I'm running multiple game servers, and every of them has the same `name` but different `PID` and the `port` number. I would like to match the `PID` of the server which is listening on certain port, and then I would like to kill this process. I need that in order to complete my bash script.

Is that even possible? Because it didn't find yet any solutions on the web.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

The `-p` flag of `netstat` gives you PID of the process:

```
netstat -l -p
```

*use sudo if showing `-` instead of PID

**Edit:** The command that is needed to get PIDs of socket users in FreeBSD is `sockstat`.
As we worked out during the discussion with @Cyclone, the line that does the job is:

```
sockstat -4 -l | grep :80 | awk '{print $3}' | head -1
```

Comment: `netstat: 80: unknown or uninstrumented protocol` used the `80` (nginx) port for testing purpoes. Not worked.

Comment: `netstat -l -p 80` , when I do `netstat -l -p` I'm getting the manual: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=q9jeQSBj

Comment: try `netstat -nlp | grep :80` instead

Comment: `netstat: option requires an argument -- p`

Comment: Hmm, you have different `-p` option. Try `sockstat -4 -l`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9265/discussion-between-stanwise-and-cyclone)

Comment: @jasonbrittain On Cygwin, windows native `netstat` is called. It has other syntax.

Comment: this answer is wrong: netstat: option requires an argument -- p

Comment: On OS X here. The -p flag is used to specify the protocol filter in the native netstat.

Comment: I think you're looking for `-b`

Comment: For processes run from other users the output includes the process, but won't include its PID. I had to use `sudo netstat ...`

Comment: @stanwise You can turn this `grep :80 | awk '{print $3}'` into a single statement like so: `awk '/:80/{print $3}'`. I am sure you probably know this now but I think it'll be good for the others searching who stumble upon this to know.

Answer (score 158):

Short version which you can pass to kill command:

```
lsof -i:80 -t
```

Comment: This also includes processes that are _connected_ on that port.  `lsof -i4TCP:80 -sTCP:LISTEN -t` is probably what you want, instead.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wanted to kill a process by searching for the port it is running at.

Comment: @Nevir what do you mean by " also includes processes that are connected on that port"? Can you please explain?

Comment: `kill -9 \`lsof -i:80 -t\`` for ease of copying

Answer (score 17):

`netstat -p -l | grep $PORT` and `lsof -i :$PORT`  solutions are good but I prefer `fuser $PORT/tcp` extension syntax to POSIX (which work for `coreutils`) as with pipe:

```
pid=`fuser $PORT/tcp`
```

it prints pure pid so you can drop `sed` magic out.

One thing that makes `fuser` my lover tools is ability to send signal to that process directly (this syntax is also extension to POSIX):

```
$ fuser -k $port/tcp       # with SIGKILL
$ fuser -k -15 $port/tcp   # with SIGTERM
$ fuser -k -TERM $port/tcp # with SIGTERM
```

Also -k is supported by FreeBSD: http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=fuser

Comment: fuser us neater and concise

Answer (score 11):

`netstat -nlp` should tell you the PID of what's listening on which port.

Comment: `netstat: 80: unknown or uninstrumented protocol` used the `80` (nginx) port for testing purpoes. Not worked.

Answer (score 4):

*Syntax:*

> kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:portnumber)

*Example:*
To kill the process running at port 4200, run following command

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:4200)
```

Tested in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Since sockstat wasn't natively installed on my machine I hacked up stanwise's answer to use netstat instead..

```
netstat -nlp | grep -E "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:2000" | awk '{print $7}' | sed -e "s/\/.*//g""
```

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to **programmatically** -- using only Bash -- kill the process listening on a given port.

Let's say the port is 8089, then here is how I did it:

```
badPid=$(netstat --listening --program --numeric --tcp | grep "::8089" | awk '{print $7}' | awk -F/ '{print $1}' | head -1)
kill -9 $badPid
```

I hope this helps someone else! I know it is going to help my team.

Comment: Here is the function I use to do it:
`function kill-listener {
        lsof -i:$1 -t | xargs kill -9
}`
Using your example of port 8089: `kill-listener 8089`

Answer (score 3):

on windows, the netstat option to get the pid's is -o and -p  selects a protocol filter, ex.:
netstat -a -p tcp -o