# NodeJS throw new TypeError

Tags: javascript, node.js

When i try to run my JS file i get this error:

```
http.js:783
    throw new TypeError('first argument must be a string or Buffer');
```

I was following this tutorial which didn't seem to mention the problem [Tutorial Link](http://arminboss.de/blog/2013/tutorial-how-to-create-a-basic-chat-with-node-js/)

My JS file has:

```
var http = require('http'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    sanitize = require('validator').sanitize;

var app = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
        response.end();
    });
}).listen(1337);

var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    socket.on('message_to_server', function(data) { 
        var escaped_message = sanitize(data["message"]).escape();
        io.sockets.emit("message_to_client",{ message: escaped_message }); 
    });
});
```

I have Socket.io and validator installed in my node_modules folder. I'm quite new to this sort of stuff and looks like this tutorial wasn't a good starting choice, I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: @tymeJV wish i knew - i can't find what node folder the file is in!

Comment: [This is what's throwing.](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.22/lib/http.js#L853)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing any error checking, and I'd bet that `readFile` is throwing an error.  This means `data` is undefined, so when you try to `response.write(data)`, the http module throws an error.

**Always** check the error parameter in your callback functions, and handle it appropriately.

```
fs.readFile("client.html", 'utf-8', function (error, data) {
    if (error) {
        response.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(error.toString());
    } else {
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        response.write(data);
    }
    response.end();
});
```

Comment: Ah i got a more useful error now `Error: ENOENT, open 'client.html'`

Comment: @Dave: `ENOENT` means the file cannot be found.

Comment: i know but see here: http://5.77.44.77/~civilian/socketio/ its definitely there =/

Comment: Node probably isn't resolving paths how you expect.  Paths are resolved relative to *the current working directory*, not where your script file is located.  Try using [`__dirname`](http://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_dirname) -- `__dirname + '/client.html'`

Comment: I've changed it not sure if it worked because when i ran the js file again i got `Error: listen EADDRINUSE`, i don't know how to free up the port to run it again. =/

Comment: Kill the process listening to the port you're trying to use ([*nix](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9856590/201952)/[Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/48198/201952)), or use a different port.